Fail installing triton
after installing triton on windows and running a program on it, this error shows up
File d:\Anaconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\triton\runtime\build.py:65, in _build(name, src,      srcdir, library_dirs, include_dirs, libraries)
     63 include_dirs = include_dirs + [srcdir, py_include_dir]
     64 cc_cmd = _cc_cmd(cc, src, so, include_dirs, library_dirs, libraries)
---> 65 ret = subprocess.check_call(cc_cmd)
     66 if ret == 0:
     67     return so

……
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1539                              # no special security
   1540                              None, None,
   1541                              int(not close_fds),
   1542                              creationflags,
   1543                              env,
   1544                              cwd,
   1545                              startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Can't find the file

my operating system is windows x86_64, using anaconda python3.11 and cuda 12.1
I tried to relocate the path of gcc but failed
